# Store and retreive RSA private key in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, encryption, certificate, certificate-store

I have a pretty simple scenario/requirement:

1. Generate RSA private/public key pair through OpenSSL or any online RSA key pair generator
2. Save the private key to the windows internal store (so it does not lay around as just a file somewhere
3. Create a PowerShell script, that looks into the store, locates the key, and uses it.
   (basically, I will have a PS script, to which I send a 3rd party tool already encrypted password, and I expect that PS script to decrypt that password using a locally stored private key and use it on-the-fly)

This so far showed an unreachable goal, because:

- I haven't found a way, how to import .pem file with the key
- .cer file apparently does not contain the key
- the only way (so far what I have found) how to import the key is conversion to .pfx file, which can be imported, BUT
- .pfx file cannot be read as plain text - there seems to be no reasonable way from Powershell to locate the key and read it for usage in decryption
- there is a module PSPKI, but it seems to accept the file and not the stored/installed certificate/key.

So anyone has any idea, how can I import a simple private key to Windows for later read-out from PowerShell for further usage?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this class to load the PFX: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=net-7.0

```
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("c:\my.pfx", "password");
```

Next step is to open the store. After you checked which one fits best (machine or user) you can use [X509Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store?view=net-7.0) to read and write there. Do not forget the `Open` method. When a certificate with private key (off) is added the key ist stored and the file can be deleted.

Comment: Hello Daniel, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this does not meet the requirements, as this API takes a FILE. This is exactly what I do not want, as I don't want anybody to stumble upon it and mess with it, that I why I am looking for a way, how to store the key to the Windows internal key/cert store, from where it would be retrievable only by script or with exact permission to access this cert store and view the content.